# Using a smaller font for a part of chapter name

Tags: chapters, fontsize

I would like to use a smaller font for a part of a chapter name.
This works fine, but the inconvenience is that the smaller text is not at the same level as the normal text.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello {\large(there)}}
\end{document}
```

The above code gives something like this:

[image]

But I would prefer something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do in the table of contents. Here are two possibilities. Adjust the parameter to `\smaller` to suit.

### Smaller also in the TOC

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}  % openany just for the example
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just for the example

\usepackage{relsize}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\centersmaller}[1]{%
  \raisebox{.5\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`T-\height}{\smaller[3]#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Hello \centersmaller{(there)}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Normal size in the TOC

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}  % openany just for the example
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just for the example

\usepackage{relsize}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\centersmaller}[1]{%
  \raisebox{.5\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`T-\height}{\smaller[3]#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\centersmaller[1]{#1}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\chapter{Hello \centersmaller{(there)}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a \raisebox{}

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello \raisebox{1ex}{\large(there)}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not need the sophisticated solution in egreg’s answer, you may take care of the problem with table of contents using relsize directly (as indicated in my yesterday’s comment):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Hello \textsmaller[2]{\raisebox{.15ex}{(there)}}}
\chapter{Hello (here)}

\end{document}
```

\smaller[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd6eK.png) reduces font size base on the actual font size in the Table of Contents. Using 'ex' as dimension secure a raise relative to font size. How much to raise is simple trial and error.

[image: TOC]
[image: Text]

Comment: The `\large` will have adverse effects in the TOC

Comment: @egreg For sure. Name either has to skip TOC, write a macro to strip the added commands, or perhaps use relative sizes for font size and distance to raise. This type of direct formatting is not necessary a good idea. I assume you have a better solution to the problem :-)